# ApexChart fixed labels x asis for rangeBar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, timeline, apexcharts

This is my chart option code:

```
const options = {
  chart: {
    type: "rangeBar",
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [
        {
          x: "Code",
          y: [Date.UTC(2019, 3, 2, 12, 30), Date.UTC(2019, 3, 2, 13, 0)],
        },
        {
          x: "Code",
          y: [Date.UTC(2019, 3, 2, 15, 30), Date.UTC(2019, 3, 2, 16, 0)],
        },
        {
          x: "Code",
          y: [Date.UTC(2019, 3, 2, 18, 0), Date.UTC(2019, 3, 2, 19, 0)],
        },
        {
          x: "Code",
          y: [Date.UTC(2019, 3, 2, 22, 0), Date.UTC(2019, 3, 2, 24, 0)],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      horizontal: true,
    },
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: "datetime",
  },
};
```

And this is the result:
[image]

I don't know how to add fixed labels from 00:00 to 24:00 hour format. That's my problem.
I also did this but doesn't work:

```
xaxis: {
    type: "category",
    categories: ["00:00", ..., "24:00"]
  },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally i fixed this in this repo:

https://github.com/mortezasabihi/apexchart-timeline